# cancelling/aborting a request

Tags: python, flask

I’m wondering if there’s a way to cancel/abort a GET/POST request that was sent to a Flask server. For example, user (which is logged inn with SESSIONS) presses “RUN” button to start a process on an uploaded file, but they realize it’s the wrong file so now press the “CANCEL” button. Is there a way for the server to stop the request so no more resources are used for the cancelled request?

RUN button -> send request  (with a way to identify the request so we can cancel it if needed)
CANCEL button -> send request to cancel (cancel the spesific request by some reference)

What would be a good way to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: raise an exception when the button is pressed

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, could u elaborate further or provide an example?

Comment: Not sure if it works or not but I think you can just add a button and when the user clicks on the button you can redirect it to the same page where it has been uploading a file.